# Reading ORC Spark DataFrames with special characters

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I'm loading some ORC tables from S3 but I'm facing some issues with character encoding I guess. In the resulting dataframe, characters like 'á', 'â', 'ñ', etc will not display correctly (all fields are StringType) and I can't find any spark/sql/hive properties that could be relevant to character enconding, charsets or anything like that. Anyone ever dealt with this before?

Comment: Is that a _display_ issue i.e. your client tool expects ISO but gets UTF8, or was the data screwed when loaded into ORC i.e. the guy forgot to check/convert the original data to UTF8?

Comment: I believe it's a display issue. I made a quick test with a tool that transforms ORC files into json (not related to spark) and the resulting json shows my data correctly. That's the main reason I suspected the problem was when spark read/converted it to dataframe. Also, reading the same data from Cassandra instead ORC files does display it correctly.

Comment: Recent Hive versions have a TBLPROPERTIES option to set a specific charset -- but for _text files_, not for Parquet or ORC that are supposed to contain "massaged" data...

Comment: I see no reason why Spark would not assume that your ORC files text is in UTF8. What is the default charset for your JVM, by the way...?

Comment: Turns out that one of the machines in the client's environment had it's JVM charset configured as _windows-1252_, thus generating this messy data. I'm still wondering though, how did the java orc-tool I tested was able to properly convert the data to JSON. Well, thanks for helping me figure this out, Samson.